# Showing that two matrices are similar by showing they are similar to the same diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

The exercise gives two matrices $A$ and $B$ and asks you to show they are similar by showing that they are similar to the same diagonal matrix, and then after that find and invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$.

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 2\\[0.3em]
    1 & -1 & 1\\[0.3em]
    2 & 0 & 1\\[0.3em]
    \end{bmatrix},
%    
B = \begin{bmatrix}
    -3 & -2 & 0\\[0.3em]
    6 & 5 & 0\\[0.3em]
    4 & 4 & -1\\[0.3em]
    \end{bmatrix}
$$

I started with with calculating the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ like so:
$$
det(A) = det(\begin{bmatrix}
    1-\lambda & 0 & 2\\[0.3em]
    1 & -1-\lambda & 1\\[0.3em]
    2 & 0 & 1-\lambda\\[0.3em]
    \end{bmatrix})= \lambda^3-\lambda^2-5\lambda-3 = (\lambda-3)(\lambda+1)^2
$$

Which gives $\lambda = -1, 3$. Taking $\lambda = -1$ gives $$[A--1 \cdot I|0] = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 0 & 2 & 0\\[0.3em]
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\[0.3em]
    2 & 0 & 2 & 0\\[0.3em]
    \end{bmatrix}=
%
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\[0.3em]
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\[0.3em]
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\[0.3em]
    \end{bmatrix}
    $$

But this is where I get stuck, because $x_2$ is a free variable, and so this gives

$$
E_{-1}=\Bigg\{s
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\[0.3em]
1\\[0.3em]
0\\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}+
%
t\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\[0.3em]
0\\[0.3em]
1\\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}\Bigg\} = span
%
\Bigg(\begin{bmatrix}
0\\[0.3em]
1\\[0.3em]
0\\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix},
%
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\[0.3em]
0\\[0.3em]
1\\[0.3em]
\end{bmatrix}
\Bigg)
$$ 
right? I thought $P =\{E_{-1}, E_{-1}, E_{3}\}$ for example, so how does this work? I might be completely missing the mark, but I thought you had to calculate the eigenvalues of matrix $A$ and $B$, and if they are the same, then they are similar, then after this, calculate the eigenvectors of matrix $A$ to obtain matrix $P$, and then plug these matrices into the formula given above ($P^{-1}AP=B$) to see if it's true or not?

I uploaded pictures of how I've done it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckbew.jpg), is that the correct way?

Comment: Why are you stuck? You seem to have just stopped rather than continuing doing precisely what you say you think you should be doing.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I thought $E_{-1}$ was supposed to be 1 vector, so then I must have done something wrong. Should I just continue with $\lambda = 3$ and then use that together with $E_{-1}$ to obtain matrix $P$?

Comment: Why should it be just one vector? You only have two eigenvalues, so you need two eigenvectors from one of them to be able to diagonalize.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Okay thanks, I must have been confused for some reason. Is my reasoning at the bottom correct and should I just continue with that?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I edited in pictures of my work, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an eigenvalue of multplicity, you will get multiple eigenvalues associated with that eigenvalue.

$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    1 & -1\\
    2 & 0\\
    \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
    0&-1 \\
    1&0\\
    0&1\\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
    0&1 \\
    -1&0\\
    0&-1\\
    \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0&-1 \\
    1&0\\
    0&1\\
    \end{bmatrix}(-I)$

Find the 3rd eigenvetor and you will have

$AP = P\begin{bmatrix} -1&\\&-1\\&&3\end{bmatrix}\\
P^{-1}AP = \begin{bmatrix} -1&\\&-1\\&&3\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the matrices $A$ and $B$ are invertible with the eigenvalues $-1, -1, 3$.

First, find a matrix $P_1$ such that $P_1^{-1} A P_1 = D = \mbox{diag}(-1, -1, 3)$.

Next, find a matrix $P_2$ such that $P_2^{-1} B P_2 = D = \mbox{diag}(-1, -1, 3)$.

This gives: $P_1^{-1} A P_1 = P_2^{-1} B P_2$.

That is, $P_2 P_1^{-1} A P_1 P_2^{-1} = B$.

If we define $P = P_1 P_2^{-1}$, then $P^{-1} A P = B$.

For the given problem, using MATLAB, I got

$$P_1 = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
      0  & -0.6325  &  0.6667 \\
    1.0000  &   0.4472 &   0.3333 \\
         0  &  0.6325   & 0.6667 \\ \end{array} \right] \ \mbox{and} \
 P_2 = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
  0  &  0.3801 &  -0.2673 \\
         0  & -0.3801  &  0.8018 \\
    1.0000 &   0.8433 &   0.5345 \\
 \end{array} \right].
$$

Thus,
$$
P = P_1 P_2^{-1} =
\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
  -1.2489  &  0.4152  &       0 \\
   -1.9395  & -0.8974 &   1.0000 \\
    3.7434  &  2.0793  &       0 \\
 \end{array} \right].
$$